# bash regex multiple match in one line

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I'm trying to process my text.
For example i got:

> asdf asdf get.this random random get.that
>
> get.it this.no also.this.no

My desired output is:

> get.this get.that
>
> get.it

So regexp should catch only this pattern (get.\w), but it has to do it recursively because of multiple occurences in one line, so easiest way with sed

```
sed 's/.*(REGEX).*/\1/'
```

does not work (it shows only first occurence).
Probably the good way is to use grep -o, but i have old version of grep and -o flag is not available.

Answer (score 2):

This `grep` may give what you need:

```
grep -o "get[^ ]*" file
```

Comment: This is a good solution though multiple matches on same line with be outputted on a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Try awk:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/get\.\w+/){print $i}}}' file.txt
```

You might need to tweak the regex between the slashes for your specific issue. Sample output:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/get\.\w+/){print $i}}}' file.txt
get.this
get.that
get.it
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk -v patt="^get" '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
        if ($i ~ patt) 
            printf "%s%s", $i, OFS; 
    print ""
}' <<< "$text"
```

bash

```
while read -a words; do
    for word in "${words[@]}"; do
        if [[ $word  == get* ]]; then
            echo -n "$word "
        fi
    done
    echo
done <<< "$text"
```

perl

```
perl -lane 'print join " ", grep {$_ =~ /^get/} @F' <<< "$text"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/\bget\.\S+/{s//\n&\n/g;s/[^\n]*\n([^\n]*)\n[^\n]*/\1 /g;s/ $//}' file
```

or if you want one per line:

```
sed -r '/\n/!s/\bget\.\S+/\n&\n/g;/^get/P;D' file
```